# $f: C_*\to D_*$ is a homotopy equivalence between chain complexes. Prove that $f_*: H_n(C_*)\to H_n(D_*)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

**Suppose that $f: C_*\to D_*$ is a homotopy equivalence between chain complexes. Prove that $f_*: H_n(C_*)\to H_n(D_*)$ is an isomorphism for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.**

I have tried to do the following:

Since $f: C_*\to D_*$ is a homotopy equivalence then there exists a homomorphism $g: D_*\to C_*$ such that $(f\circ g)_*=f_*\circ g_*: H_n(D_*)\to H_n(D_*)$ is homotopic to $Id: H_n(D_*)\to H_n(D_*)$ and $(g\circ f)_*=g_*\circ f_*: H_n(C_*)\to H_n(C_*)$ is homotopic to $Id: H_n(C_*)\to H_n(C_*)$. But what I want is that $f_*\circ g_*=Id$ and $g_*\circ f_*=Id$, In order to conclude that $f_*$ is bijective and since it is already a homomorphism then $f_*$ is an isomorphism. How can I do this? Thank you very much.

***Edit:*** 
 We say that a $f_*: C_*\to D_*$ homomorphism between chain complexes is a homotopy equivalence if there is a $g_*: D_*\to C_*$ homomorphism such that $f_*\circ g_*$ and $g_*\circ f_*$ are homotopic homomorphisms to the corresponding identity homomorphism.

Comment: It's homotop**y** equivalence and the subscript of the maps should be $n$, not $*$, since you decided to fix $n$ on one side of the equation.

Comment: Could you write down the definition of homotopic in this context? If you don't know it, it's time to look it up!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yes, 
I already edited that.

Comment: You defined "homotopy equivalence", but your definition includes the word **homotopic**. The answer to your question lies in the definition of this word in the present context. Write it down as well, and try to solve your question again.